# UIButtons in UICollectionReusableView header

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to add a few UIButtons to a collectionviews header, but am having difficulties discovering which header is pressed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding the `UIButtons` programmatically the fastest is to add a tag with the section to the button.

```
UIButton.tag = x //where x is the section number
```

Then in the action you can check the tag.